# Is memory in same section always allocated contiguously?

Tags: c

```
char a_1[512];
int some_variable;
char a_2[512];
main()
{
        ...
}
```

Here in the above program, I have declared some variables, all in bss section of the code. Considering that I have kept in mind the alignment issues, can I be sure that the memory allocated for those 3 variables will **always** be contiguous?

Comment: No. They wouldn't be.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Can you please give an example or a scenario where they wouldn't be?

Comment: the scenario you provided. The C standard doesn't specify anything about contiguousness, and therefore compilers can do as they please.

Comment: Assumptions in C mean that you're just shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala what about using the same compiler? would that be guaranteed?

Comment: The motivation (of hunting a bug) should go into the question. You probably need watchpoints!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Considering that I have kept in mind the alignment issues, can I be sure that the memory allocated for those 3 variables will always be contiguous?

Certainly **not**. Read the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), and you won't find any guarantee about that.

Different compilers are likely to order variables differently, in particular when they are [optimizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler). Some variables might even stay in a register, and not even have any memory location. In practice some compilers are following the order of the source, others are using some different order.

And you practically could customize (perhaps with some pain) your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or your [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiler to change that order. And this does happen in practice. For example, recent versions of the GCC kernel might be configured with some GCC [plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) which could reorder variables. With GCC or Clang you might also add some [variable attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) to alter that order.

BTW, if you need some specific order, you could pack the fields in some `struct` e.g. code:

```
struct {
  char a_1[512];
  int some_variable;
  char a_2[512];
} my_struct;

#define a_1 my_struct.a_1
#define some_variable my_struct.some_variable
#define a_2 my_struct.a_2
```

BTW, some old versions of GCC had an optional optimization pass which reordered (in some cases) fields in `struct`-s (but recent GCC removed that optimization pass).

In a comment (which should go into your question) you mention hunting some bug. Consider [using the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and its [watchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Breakpoints.html#index-watchpoints) (and/or [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)). Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info when compiling (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Maybe you want also [instrumentation options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) like `-fsanitize=address` etc...

Beware of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Yeah thanks, I suggested valgrind already to my collegue who is doing it.

Comment: This is answer is correct, but I have to note that this should only be a quick fix. Any code that depends on order of variables (even struct members) should most likely be rewritten completely.

Comment: In some legitimate cases you do care about order of fields.